# Bot de Telegram en PHP no responde

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Estoy haciendo un bot de telegram que cuando ponga el comando `/start` me devuelva el mensaje `Hola`. No hay manera, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Aparte, quería añadir el valor del mensaje cuando ponga `/add` a la base de datos para después realizar un sumatorio. Es como que el bot no puede darme el valor o devolverlo.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("Fallo conexion" . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "siii";

$token = "telegramtokenbot";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$message = $update['message']['text'];
$chatId = 'elchatid';

$arr = explode(' ',trim($message));
$command = $arr[0];

$message = substr(strstr($message," "), 1);

switch ($command) {
    case "/start":
        $response = "Hola!";
        sendMessage($chatId, $response);
        break;

    case "/add":
        $str = $updates['message']['reply_to_message']['text'];
        $insert = "INSERT INTO devolucion VALUES ('$str')";
        mysql_query($conn,$insert);
        sendMessage($chatId, $str);
        echo "ok";
        break;
}

function sendMessage($chatId, $response){
    $url = $GLOBALS[website].'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$chatId.'&parse_mode=HTML&text='.urlencode($response);
    file_get_contents($url);;
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

PD. La conexión a la base de datos está perfecta, me devuelve el `echo`.

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que es `$arr`? El `switch` hace uso de `$command` que viene de uno de los índices de esa matriz. Si no está definido ese índice el `switch` iría al `default` (o no haría nada si no lo hay).

Comment: disculpa no copié esa parte del codigo: $arr = explode(' ',trim($message));

Comment: Por cierto, aunque estás usando mysqli para establecer la conexión, luego intentas usar `mysql_query` para hacer la consulta SQL. Además, lo haces concatenando cadenas, que te [podría generar problemas graves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) en tu aplicación debido a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). PD: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código correcto en ella.

Comment: cierto, ya está corregido mysqli_query y ya está añadido el codigo

Comment: No deberías poner las modificaciones o correcciones de código en comentarios, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/313115/edit) y modifica allí el código. Gracias.

Comment: Me has cogido editanto el codigo, muchas gracias, alguna idea de porque no funciona?

Comment: No veo la implementación de `sendMessage()`, por lo que no sé si hace bien su trabajo. ¿Has probado a usar un `file_put_contents('log.txt', $update . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` (o `file_put_contents('log.txt', $update);` si sólo quieres quedarte con el último) inmediatamente posterior al `file_get_contents()`? Eso te permitiría depurar los mensajes recibidos a través del webhook y probar "offline" el código.

Comment: Ahora veo la implementación de `sendMessage()`, deberías usar `$GLOBALS['website']` ya que en caso contrario estás generando una advertencia de constante `website` no definida. ¿Has mirado qué advertencias y errores te aparecen en el log del servidor?

Comment: no sale ninguna advertencia, es como si no entrase ni al switch, he intentado meter un log pero no recibo nada

Comment: Si metes el log y no recibes nada podría ser por muchos motivos, como que estés usando un webhook sobre un certificado HTTPS que no es válido, o que no hayas configurado correctamente la URL, etc. ¿Has probado a depurar la ejecución del script PHP inyectando datos desde, por ejemplo, javascript?

Comment: Te he dado un voto positivo para que tengas suficiente reputación para usar el chat. [Continuemos allí la conversación](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101702/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-pedro).

Comment: Ya está solucionado era el webhook que no estaba configurado. Ahora tengo otro que es que pongo /add 400 y me añade a la db /add 400 en vez de solo el valor (400)

Comment: Eso es sencillo, usa `$arr = explode(' ', trim($message), 2);` y en `$arr[0]` tendrás el comando y en `$arr[1]` el/los parámetro/s.